# Matching two files with awk codes

Tags: file, awk, matching

There are two files

first.file

- M1
- M2
- M3

...

second.file

- A1 M1
- A2 M1
- A2 M3
- A3 M2
- A3 M4
- A3 M5

....

I want to match first.file to second.file My result file should be like that:

result.file

- A1 M1
- A2 M1
- A2 M3
- A3 M2

How can I do that with awk codes ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '
  BEGIN { while (getline < "first.file") { file1[$0]=1 } }
  $2 in file1 { print }
' <second.file
```

Comment: +1 for using arrays, but I would write `awk 'NR == FNR {file1[$0]; next} $2 in file1' first.file second.file`

Answer (score 2):

Use the below:

```
grep -f firstfile secondfile
```

`grep` is enough.
even though we can do this with `awk` too,i prefer `grep`

If you still insist on awk,Then i have a very simple solution in awk too.

`awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}($0 in a)' file2 file1`

**Explanation:**

Put file2 entries into an array. Then iterate file1, each time finding those entries in the array.

Comment: some systems don't recognize `grep -f ...`, so then try `fgrep -f firstfile secondfile`. Good luck.